# How to use flex row to elements with different heights

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For example I'm  trying to stack blockes with different heights like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.box2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

How It should be:
[image]

Comment: is flex mandatory?

Comment: you should use differents colors, it takes me a while to understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution (but more a hack for this case than a generic solution) is to keep all what you have and adjust margin of last element.

*Of course the margin-top value will depend on ther other values*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.box2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
}
.box2:last-child {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-top:-25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @NikitaSmith This is a workaround but make sure that this solution will only be valid for this case as long as the rows aren't wrapping. Once you wrap your rows for other devices you'll see that div get messed up.

Comment: @Highdef for the other devices we can simply add media query and remove the property i added ;) i think it won't be an issue in this particular case but as i mention it cannot be a geniric solution maybe the idea can be considerd and used by adjusting the values in other cases.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this can only be solved if you nest the two `<div class="box2">` inside of a `<div class="box">` wrapper

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/7j6uknck/2/

Comment: Yes. It's right. But I want to work with orders of the elements for different devices. Use container for blockes will not work for it.

Comment: You don't want to change the html structure?

Answer (score 0):

The other solution gave a working flexbox example for that particular scenario.

**But** if flexbox isn't mandatory and you don't want to change the html structure, you can make use of float for your particular layout.

```css
.container { 
}
.box {
float:left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.box2 {
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to use order flex to change position of the elements for different devices. Use float is not the best decision.

Comment: @NikitaSmith Thought you didn't want to change the html structure like you mentioned in the other comment.